# Proving that $ (\exists y \in \mathbb{R})(\forall x \in \mathbb{R})\left(x^2+y<0\right) $ is false

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How to prove that this is false.
$$
(\exists y \in \mathbb{R})(\forall x \in \mathbb{R})\left(x^2+y<0\right)
$$

I know by intuition, that there is no y, where for every x, $x^2+y<0$ is valid .

Comment: Formalize your intuition. How do you know that, say, $y=5$ won't work?

Comment: Write down the negation of your proposition and prove it.

Comment: Let me know if this is correct: So when there would be y, such that for every $x \in R$ expression $x^2 + y < 0$, than we could say that x is $x = sqrt(1-y)$ and than $1-y+y<0$ that is $1<0$, concluding that proposition is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y\in \mathbb R$.

- If $y<0$ then $-y>0$ and $\sqrt{-y}^2+y=-y+y\geq 0$;
- If $y\geq0$ then $\forall x\in \mathbb R, x^2+y\geq0$.

Either way, there is $x\in \mathbb R$ such that $x^2+y\geq0$.

The stated assertion is therefore false.

Comment: Why would you divide proof into cases? Why is it important that $y < 0 $ and if $y >= 0$? (BTW I'm noob when it comes to proofing stuff, so maybe this is ridiculous question but I just don't get it)

Comment: That's a very good question ; it is a very important method in mathematics which is called the method by disjunction of cases("méthode par disjonction des cas" in French, i'm not sure in english, @Anne Bauval could certainly help)